# Why is Photoimage put() slow?

Tags: python, tkinter

When manipulating `PhotoImage` objects with:

```
import tkinter as tk

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="myFile.gif")
for x in range(0,1000):
  for y in range(0,1000):
    img.put("{red}", (x, y))
```

The `put` operation takes a very long time. Is there a faster method of doing this?

Comment: I would say that its probably not just the `put()` call that is slow, but the fact that you are doing a nested for loop (1000^2) which is very slow. But @soulcheck has the right answer for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a bounding box:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
label = Label(root)
label.pack()
img = PhotoImage(width=300,height=300)
data = ("{red red red red blue blue blue blue}")
img.put(data, to=(20,20,280,280))
label.config(image=img)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Realize this answer is old, but could you explain how using `"{red red red red blue blue blue blue}"` as an input for data creates the columns of colors?

Comment: Figured it out, thanks! In case someone else comes across this and has a similar question [this article](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/PhotoImage) explains it well.

Comment: @JetBlue: Your link is dead, sadly :(

Comment: @PhoemueX Here's an [archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20170512214049/http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/PhotoImage)

Comment: Here's a working link the [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170512214049id_/http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/PhotoImage) @JetBlue was referring to.

Answer (score 6):

Simply using the `to` optional parameter of the `put()` command is enough, no need to create a complex string:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

img = tk.PhotoImage(width=1000, height=1000)
data = 'red'
img.put(data, to=(0, 0, 1000, 1000))
label = tk.Label(root, image=img).pack()

root_window.mainloop()
```

---

## Further observations

I couldn't find much in the way of documentation for PhotoImage, but the `to` parameter scales the data much more efficiently than a standard loop would. Here's some info I would have found helpful that doesn't seem to be properly documented well online.

The `data` parameter takes in a string of space-separated color values that are either named ([official list](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/colors.htm)), or an 8-bit color hex code. The string represents an array of colors to be repeated per pixel, where rows with more than one color are contained in curly braces and columns are just space separated. The rows must have the same number of columns/colors.

```
acceptable:
3 column 2 row: '{color color color} {color color color}'
1 column 2 row: 'color color', 'color {color}'
1 column 1 row: 'color', '{color}'

unacceptable:
{color color} {color}
```

If using a named color containing spaces, it must be encased in curly braces. ie. '{dodger blue}'

Here are a couple examples to illustrate the above in action, where a lengthy string would be required:

```
img = tk.PhotoImage(width=80, height=80)
data = ('{{{}{}}} '.format('{dodger blue} ' * 20, '#ff0000 ' * 20) * 20 +
        '{{{}{}}} '.format('LightGoldenrod ' * 20, 'green ' * 20) * 20)
img.put(data, to=(0, 0, 80, 80))
```

[image]

```
data = ('{{{}{}}} '.format('{dodger blue} ' * 20, '#ff0000 ' * 10) * 20 +
        '{{{}{}}} '.format('LightGoldenrod ' * 20, 'green ' * 10) * 10)
```

[image]

Comment: I love this answer. Saved me a lot of trouble. I did find the repetition a bit confusing, as I wanted to update every pixel in my image. I made [a gist](https://gist.github.com/samclane/7495aaad7edcc8fac29e8876baf0265e) showing how I update an image pixel-by-pixel using `put` and `to=`.

Answer (score 3):

Try constructing a 2d array of colors and call `put` with that array as parameter.

Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="myFile.gif")
# "#%02x%02x%02x" % (255,0,0) means 'red'
line = '{' + ' '.join(["#%02x%02x%02x" % (255,0,0)] * 1000) + '}'
img.put(' '.join([line] * 1000))
```